# Improving the Performance of FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, c++, filesystemwatcher

I have the following code which registers a `FileSystemWatcher` and then runs some method `DoRequiedWork()` Whenever a Write Event occurs on the specified file. There is also some logic in there to prevent multiple events from firing on each Write (with `lastRead` and `lastWriteTime`):

```
// To prevent multiple events from firing
static DateTime lastRead = DateTime.MinValue;
static string UserName = GetUserName();

private static void Run()
{
    // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
    {
        Path = $@"\\file\home$\{UserName}\Application Data",
        NotifyFilter =  
            NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
        Filter = "filetowatch.txt"
    };

    // Activate
    watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    while (true)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}

private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    var lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(e.FullPath);

    if (lastWriteTime == lastRead) return;

    DoRequiredWork();

    lastRead = lastWriteTime; 
}
```

I would like to implement this using the `c++` api `ReadDirectoryChangesW` in an attempt to improve performance, but I am not sure how to do this.

I checked [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadDirectoryChangesW.html), and can see that the signature can be defined as:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
 static extern bool ReadDirectoryChangesW(IntPtr hDirectory, IntPtr lpBuffer,
    uint nBufferLength, bool bWatchSubtree, uint dwNotifyFilter, out uint
    lpBytesReturned, IntPtr lpOverlapped,
    ReadDirectoryChangesDelegate lpCompletionRoutine);
```

I would like to start looking at how to create this, but first wanted to check whether or not this will actually perform better than the standard, managed c# `FileSystemWatcher`.

Alternatively (or in addition to), I would like to know if there is a better way of keeping the application running in the background (with no UI) than:

```
while (true)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

As I get the feeling this may not be the best way of keeping an app open, but I am not sure.

Is anyone able to advise?

Comment: [`FileSystemWatcher` ALREADY uses `ReadDirectoryChanges`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/io/system/io/FileSystemWatcher.cs), so you are unlikely to improve things by doing it yourself.

Comment: During the development of .NET Core 1.0, Microsoft does identify multiple issues on performance in this area. You will have to wait till they land those on .NET Framework, or you develop a .NET Core 1.0 RTM app right now.

Comment: @MatthewWatson that's not 100% true if Microsoft does have bugs in this class.

Comment: @LexLi Interesting - do you have a link which talks about that?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I could not find the old items from GitHub's crappy search, but this new item looks interesting too, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8059

Comment: @LexLi Well, one of the downsides listed for polling is that its "generally considered to be less performant than the OS's watching API"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're holding on to a thread in your Run method. Don't do that. Instead keep a static reference around. It looks like you're watching a networkshare. Don't expect high performance as that not only involves the Disk subsystem but also the Network subsystem to be involved (on your end and on the server). There way too many factors involved to expect that invoking the same API natively would all of a sudden give a massive performance boast.

```
static FileSystemWatcher watcher;

private static void Run()
{
    // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
    // if you're watching a network share, don't expect huge performance
    // as the network is involved
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
    {
        Path = $@"\\file\home$\{UserName}\Application Data",
        NotifyFilter =  
            NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
        Filter = "filetowatch.txt"
    };

    // Activate
    watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += (s,e) => { 
      var w = watcher as IDisposable;
      if (w != null) w.Dispose(); 
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rene. When you say I am `holding onto a thread` are you referring to the `While(true){sleep}` loop? I need this FileWatcher to ALWAYS watch the required folder, and couldn't think of any other way of doing it.MY other option was registering a `MOF` Subscription, but these are (annoyingly) unable to run exe or shell programs, which is what I need to do when a file change is detected.

Comment: Where do you call this from then?

Comment: This is in a C# Executable (`Run()` is just called inside `Main()`), and the event handler allows me to call a second exe. When I tried creating a WMI FileWatcher using MOF and WQL subscriptions it failed because these are unable to interact with the UI or call any shell commands. The reason why I originally preferred MOF/WQL is because these don't require an EXE running in the background to monitor the folder, whereas c# `FileSystemWatcher` does (CLARITY - `DoRequiredWork()` in the question calls a separate EXE from the filesystem)

Comment: Do a Console.ReadLine() then. Or start a windows message pump, but don't keep that thread going like you did. I don't think that helps.

Comment: Okay - are you saying that `ReadLine()` will perform better than just `Wait()`ing in a `While` loop? Even if it is I don't think I can because this is a Windows Application rather than a Console Application! (to hide the console)

Comment: ReadLine iwaits on a hardware interupt. It doesn't require resources.

Comment: On a Windows app, you have a message loop. The static references stay in memory and the message pump is kept alive until either WM_EXIT or WM_CLOSE is received. Assuming you did start the message pump with Application.Run

Comment: After adding `Application.Run()` to my program underneath `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents` and removing the `while`, the program still keeps running in the background. I don't think it has affected performance at all (just based on task manager) - is there some way of checking whether this uses less resources than `while` ?

Comment: It only achieved that you're no longer wasting a thread. You probably gained less context switching. Assuming you're still watching that networkshare, everything you try to squeeze out in the watcher is fruitless.